# Bulk delete records from HBase - how to convert an RDD to Array[Byte]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have an RDD of objects that I want to bulk delete from HBase. After reading HBase documentation and examples I came up with the following code:

```
hc.bulkDelete[Array[Byte]](salesObjects, TableName.valueOf("salesInfo"),
  putRecord => new Delete(putRecord), 4)
```

However as far as I understand `salesObjects` has to be converted to `Array[Byte]`.
Since `salesObjects` is an `RDD[Sale]` how to convert it to `Array[Byte]` correctly?

I've tried `Bytes.toBytes(salesObjects)` but the method doesn't accept `RDD[Sale]` as an argument. Sale is a complex object so it will be problematic to parse each field to bytes.
For now I've converted `RDD[Sale]` to `val salesList: List[Sale] = salesObjects.collect().toList` but currently stuck with where to proceed next.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this method but I'll try to help:

- the methods accepts a RDD of any type T: https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/HBaseContext.scala#L290 ==> so you should be able to use it on your `RDD[Sale]`
- bulkDelete expects a function transforming your `Sale` object to HBase's `Delete` object (https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Delete.html)
- `Delete` object represents a row to delete. You can get an example of Delete object initialization here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_delete_data.htm
- depending on what and how you want to remove a row, you should convert the parts of your `Sales` into a byte. For instance, you want to remove the data by row key, you should extract it and put into `Delete` object

In my understanding `bulkDelete` method will accumulate `batchSize` number of Delete objects and send them into HBase at once. Otherwise, could you please show some code to get a more concrete idea of what you're trying to do ?

Doing `val salesList: List[Sale] = salesObjects.collect().toList` is not a good idea since it brings all data into your driver. Potentially it can lead to OOM problems.